# CSS List item clicked to change the content without javascript

Tags: html, css

I want to ask if this possible? I have some list like :

```
<li> Home </li>
<li> User </li>
<li> Contact </li>
```

If I click on Home, will change the content with something like .home{}, or .text{} will change and so on

Comment: You could use a checkbox hack and style the clicked version via `:checked`.. but you can't dynamically add classes in pure CSS.

Comment: is it possible to dynamically change the content?

Comment: Not really. If you were to use the checkbox approach, you could use `:after`/`:before` to make it seem like you are changing content. This only allows for 2 different toggles though.

Comment: so I need javascript to dynamically change the content with list?

Comment: Ideally, yes. CSS isn't a dynamic language.